# How can I download an updated archive of facebook page data?

Tags: facebook

I'm cleanning one of our facebook pages and when we try to download the page archive, Facebook gives us an old archive.
Is there a way to force facebook to generate a new archive ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. For Facebook end user support, please go to their Help section.

Comment: We've tried a new export after a week and we have new data in it.
It seems that the archive is updated after a week